# How do you print a limited number of characters?

Tags: c, string, formatting, printf

Sorry to put a post up about something so simple, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

```
char data[1024];
DWORD numRead;

ReadFile(handle, data, 1024, &numRead, NULL);

if (numRead > 0)
    printf(data, "%.5s");
```

My intention with the above is to read data from a file, and then only print out 5 characters. However, it prints out all 1024 characters, which is contrary to what I'm reading [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/). The goal, of course, is to do something like:

```
printf(data, "%.*s", numRead);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have your parameters in the wrong order.  The should be written:

```
printf("%.5s", data);

printf("%.*s", numRead, data);
```

The first parameter to `printf` is the format specifier followed by all the arguments (which depend on your specifier).

Comment: Is the dot (`.`) unnecessary in the format strings above?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are switching the order of arguments to `printf`:

```
printf("%.5s", data); // formatting string is the first parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling printf() correctly.

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

Which means...

```
printf("%.5s", data);
```

Answer (score -3):

You are using wrong syntax for the `printf` statement, and the .number is only for numerical variables.

So it should be

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   printf("%c", data[i]);
```

Comment: .number works just fine with character arrays, he just needs to put the arguments in the right order.

Comment: For strings, precision (i.e. the .numbers) tells printf to print no more then N characters from the string.  This is very useful if your string is not '\0' terminated.

Comment: Wow.  Learned something new.  I always just assumed.  Thanks.